# JSF facelets parameters

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

Good Afternoon in my timezone

It is my first time working with jsf.
I have two facelets (two .xhtml files) using the same managed bean, in that managed bean i want to know which facelets had call me , for instance.

In managed bean i want to have a field that is fullfilled when called by the facelet which inform me the facelet that have call me, that way i can take differnt actions,

```
In managed bean:

private String type;
if(type == "X")
  ....
else
  ....
```

Thanks in advance 
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple like this:

```
private String viewId;

public void doXxx() {
  viewId = FacesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId();
  if (viewId.equals("X")
  ...
  else
  ....
}
```